# Has a Cupertino Navigation to show the app bar but need have end drawer

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-cupertino

I'm trying to add the `CupertinoNavigationBar` with endDrawer, I try to add Gesture Detector on trailing, but isn't work, shows this:

```
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
flutter: `Scaffold.of()` called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.
flutter: No Scaffold ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to `Scaffold.of()`. This
flutter: usually happens when the context provided is from the same StatefulWidget as that whose build
```

I already tried to add the key to scaffold and try opened with the key, I try too with scaffold context in appbar

AppBar:

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
    transitionBetweenRoutes: true,
    trailing: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
    onPressed: () { 
        Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
    },),
    actionsForegroundColor: Colors.white,
    middle: Text('Lejour', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
   endDrawer: DrawerMenu() // my own class,
   body: // ...body
```

I expect my trailing icon from CupertinoNavigationBar open the endDrawer with
`Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common issue when you try to use `Scaffold.of(context)` . You should read the error log.

> No Scaffold ancestor could be found starting from the context that was
>   passed to `Scaffold.of()`

To solve your issue, use the `Builder` widget to generate a new a context.

```
trailing: Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              return IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                onPressed: () {
                  Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
                },
              );
            },
          ),
```